# Ruby instance_variable_set error inside of iterator: `market_0_home' is not allowed as an instance variable name

Tags: ruby, iterator, block, variable-assignment, each

First things first, here is the assignment of @market_0_home outside of the iteration below, just to show you I tried

```
>> @market_0_home = 3
=> 3
```

OK, no errors there, now lets try this inside of a somewhat complicated iteration

```
>> markets
=> [{"home"=>"CO", "name"=>"David Douglas"}, {"home"=>"SC", "name"=>"David Robertson"}]
>> markets.each_with_index do |market, i|
?> market.each do |name, v|
?> instance_variable_set "market_#{i}_#{name}", v
>> end
>> end
NameError: `market_0_home' is not allowed as an instance variable name
from (irb):23:in `instance_variable_set'
from (irb):23
from (irb):22:in `each'
from (irb):22
from (irb):25:in `each_with_index'
from (irb):21:in `each'
from (irb):21:in `each_with_index'
from (irb):21
>>
```

Comment: OK, there are at least two errors with this, including the main one mentioned.

Comment: Yes, I am more confused than I initially realized.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I added a `@` to the variable name on the line with the `instance_variable_set` below:

```
@market_0_home = 3
markets = [{"home"=>"CO", "name"=>"David Douglas"}, {"home"=>"SC", "name"=>"David Robertson"}]
markets.each_with_index do |market, i|
  market.each do |name, v|
    instance_variable_set "@market_#{i}_#{name}", v
  end
end
```

When I run it, it works fine.

```
=> 3
>> markets = [{"home"=>"CO", "name"=>"David Douglas"}, {"home"=>"SC", "name"=>"David Robertson"}]
=> [{"home"=>"CO", "name"=>"David Douglas"}, {"home"=>"SC", "name"=>"David Robertson"}]
>> markets.each_with_index do |market, i|
?>       market.each do |name, v|
?>           instance_variable_set "@market_#{i}_#{name}", v
>>       end
>>   end
=> [{"home"=>"CO", "name"=>"David Douglas"}, {"home"=>"SC", "name"=>"David Robertson"}]
>> @market_0_home
=> "CO"
>> @market_1_home
=> "SC"
```